# Возможно ли в си, при записи в файл через fprinf, создать ссылку на "курсор" в определенном месте, чтоб потом дописать туда необходимые данные?

Tags: c

Возможно ли в си, при записи в файл через fprinf, создать ссылку на "курсор" в определенном месте, чтоб потом дописать туда необходимые данные?

Comment: При записи в середину файла данные будут перезаписываться начиная с этого места. Если вы знаете точный размер данных, которые нужно вставить, то можно сначала в это место записать нули, а потом перезаписать их. Если это подходит, используйте `fseek`/`ftell`.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat, да, подходит, сасибо